# Is there ways to sell Chrome extension in South Korea?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've made Chrome extension program named AIRDESK. But My country South Korea doesn't included to webstore seller region list.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/pricing#seller

Of course, I can use third party payment service or making payment model with back-end development. But it requires much time and effort.

Is there a ways to use Chrome payment service? 
Or is it possible changing legal business location?

Comment: Have you already tried to set up a [merchant account in Google](https://payments.google.com/merchant/signup) and/or set a price for your extension in the [Chrome WebStore Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)?

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Yes, but without set up it is not allowed my region.

Comment: Self anwser: Google payment team replied my question yesterday. They said it is impossible to sell currently. And I must use another payment system like Paypal.